# How to limit number of entries returned from a group filter?

Tags: templating, filter, category, limit

I'm wondering how I would go about limiting the number of results returned from a set using the group filter? I only want four to show, but using the `limit()` method seems to throw errors wherever I put it. Here's my template code:

```
{% set entries = craft.entries.section('recipes').find() %}

{% for category, catEntries in entries | group('cuisineType.first().title') %}

    {% for entry in catEntries %}

       // I only want four entries shown here

    {% endfor %}

{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 5):

The reason [`limit()`](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/templating/craft.entries#limit) isn't working is that is a method on the [`ElementCriteriaModel`](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/templating/elementcriteriamodel) you get from [`craft.entries`](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/templating/craft.entries).

Because you're actually dealing with a standard array when you access `catEntries`, what you want instead is Twig's [`|slice(start, length)`](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/filters/slice.html) filter:

```
{% for entry in catEntries|slice(0, 4) %}

   // You'll only get four entries shown here

{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Worth mentioning, there is a shorthand for the `slice` filter... `catEntries[0:4]`

Comment: This worked flawlessly. Now I'm wondering if there's a way to order the categories that are returned, entries can come in any order, but I'd like my categories to output in a particular one here?